# Is it possible to run Junit test for a JAR file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

I am completely new to JUnit, I have a jar file, which is getting build using ant, now my Junit is a maven project, so I want to run the JUnit test cases on the already compiled jar file. Is it possible?

Comment: Unit tests are usualy run when a jar file is being compiled. Even more, as a rule, compiled jars do not contain unit test classes. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Currently I have a CI/CD process which first compiles the classes and then bundles the classes into the jar file (using Ant). There is an existing Junit maven project and I want to integrate it with our CI/CD pipeline. Is it possible to integrate the maven project somehow?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But, as I was saying, unit tests should be run by maven during the building process. In CI script you just have to trigger the maven's build.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Thanks a lot, one more query, is it possible to run the Junit just after the compilation of the classes? i.e., with the .class files?

Comment: Can the mavenized unit test run from the command line?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes it can run

Comment: Then just do that?

Comment: @Shankhadeep Banerjee
 How to run maven test inside jar file ? If you know how do that, please share.